# ConoHa VPS の CentOS7 における22番以外のポートからのSSH接続

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, conoha

ConoHaVPSを契約し, 初期設定を行っていたのですが, SSH接続ポートを22から変更することができません.
変更直前に接続を確認する段階で, 22番ポートからは接続できるのですが, なぜか変更先ポートへの接続の場合

```
ssh -p 10222 ssh-user-name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

とすると

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 10222: Connection refused
```

と出て拒否されてしまいます.
22番ポートの認証にはパスワードを使っています.

契約から今までに行った設定は

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- # yum update
- # adduser -m ssh-user-name
- # passwd ssh-user-name
- # vim /etc/pam.d/su

    auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid  　← コメントアウト解除

- # vim /etc/login.defs

    SU_WHEEL_ONLY yes  ← 追加

- # visudo

    %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL  ←コメントアウト済を確認

- # usermod -G wheel ssh-user-name

     ユーザーを変更して再接続

- $ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

    Port 22 <- 追加
    Port 10222 <- 追加

- $ sudo systemctl restart sshd

- $ sudo cp /usr/lib/firewalld/services/ssh.xml /etc/firewalld/services/ssh-alt.xml
- $ sudo vim /etc/firewalld/services/ssh-alt.xml

    <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/> を <port protocol="tcp" port="10222"/> に変更

- $ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
- $ sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=ssh-alt
- $ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ssh-alt

- $ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
    〜
    services: dhcpv6-client ssh ssh-alt を確認
    〜
```

です.
1回再起動もかけました.

また,

```
netstat -tanp
```

では

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
〜  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10222           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -   
tcp6       0      0 :::10222                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
〜
```

となっているのですが, 手元のPCから

```
nmap -p ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

とすると

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

となってしまいます.

どのようにすれば, 10222番ポートからSSH接続できるのでしょうか.
よろしくお願いします.

追記

```
$ iptables -L
```

とすると

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate      RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate   RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

と表示されました.

Comment: `iptables -L` の実行結果として、`INPUT`, `FORWARD`, `OUTPUT` の他にも様々なチェーンが表示されると思いますが、それはどうなっていますか？ 特に、CentOS 7 なら、`IN_public_allow` という名前のチェーンがキモになっていると思います。とはいえ、手順を見るときちんとポートが開放されているように見えるのですけど。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すみません、タイトルをちゃんと見ていませんでした。CentOS7なのですね。
だとするとiptablesではなくてfirewalldを使います。

firewalldでも10022番ポートがフィルタリングされている状況は同じです。/usr/lib/firewalld/services/ssh.xmlに以下のようにポート10022の設定を追加して、firewalldをリロードしてみてください。

```
<port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
<port protocol="tcp" port="10022"/>         <== 追加
```

以下のコマンドでリロード

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: 教えていただいた手順で, 無事任意のポートから接続することができました.
ありがとうございました.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/ssh/sshd_configのPort 22のすぐ上に
　　　　# if you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
　　　　# SELinux about this change.
　　　　# senamage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
というコメントがありますが、これはやられたのですか？
これに該当していると思われますが。

Comment: $ sestatus は
    SELinux status:                 disabled
と表示されたのでSELinuxは無効化されていると判断しました.

Answer (score 1):

手順通りやると、iptables でもしっかりポートは空くはずで、問題ないように見えるのでなかなか厄介ですね。
`netstat -tanp` の結果、10222番ポートが空いているようですが、もしかして、これは再起動前の話で、再起動後は22番ポートだけ、となってたりしませんか？
もしそうだとすれば、以下のどちらか (あるいは両方) の可能性が考えられます。

#### 可能性1: sshd を sshd.socket 経由で起動する設定になっていた

`systemctl status sshd` (あるいは `systemctl status sshd.service`)の結果が disabled で、 `systemctl status sshd.socket` の結果が enabled なら、ポートを空けるのは sshd ではなく systemd の仕事になっていますので、`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` の設定ではなく、 `systemd.socket` の設定を変更する必要があります。

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.socket /etc/systemd/system/
$ sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/systemd.socket

(ListenStream=22 の記述の直下に ListenStream=10222 という行を追加)

$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

#### 可能性2: SELinux が有効になっていた (が、設定時には無効になっていた)

SELinux が有効になっている場合、sshd が 10222 番ポートを空けられるよう設定しなければなりません。これを行っていなければ、許可されている 22 番ポートのみ空けるのに成功し、10222 番ポートは失敗します。
これで 10222 番ポートが空けられなかった場合、 `systemctl status sshd` や `journalctl` でその旨のログを見ることができます。

```
$ sudo semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 10222
```

とすることで、sshd がポートを空けることを許可できます。もし `semanage` コマンドがなければ'、`sudo yum install policycoreutils-python`。
なお、これは、可能性1のように、sshd.socket を使う設定になっていた場合でも必要になります。

Comment: $ systemctl status sshd は

    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled) 

と表示され,
$ sestatus は

    SELinux status:                 disabled

と表示されました.

Answer (score 0):

コントロールパネル→サーバ詳細画面→ネットワーク情報→「接続許可ポート」が22(SSH)になってたりして。

Answer (score 0):

Connection refusedなので、iptables でフィルタリングされているのだと思います。

```
iptables -L
```

と実行すると以下のようになっていませんか？

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

ConoHaはこのように22番ポート以外の通信はフィルタリングされる設定になっています。以下のように10022番ポートをACCEPTすると通信できるようになると思います。

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 10022 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: iptables -L の結果を追加しました.

また, 教えていただいた通り,

    iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 10222 -j ACCEPT

としても

ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 10222: Connection refused

と出て拒否されてしまいました.
22番ポートでは今まで通り接続できます.